# Why do we need to reindex Taylor Series when differentiating cosh?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

I'm doing a calculus course right now and I do not quite understand why the Taylor series needs to be reindexed when we take the derivative of cosh (second row in the picture). Can someone please explain?

[The picture with sinh and cosh derivatives in Taylor series form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3hZS.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just as well not reindex it, but the $k=0$ term is
$$(2k)\frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k)!}=0$$
You can see directly that the derivative of that term is $0$ because it is the constant $1$. Therefore reindexing it is cleaner as it leaves out unnecessary terms.

Comment: Oh so it's just for convenience. Got it, thanks!

Comment: @Nick No problem.